# Removing empty resultsets from looping through multiple tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to remove empty resultsets from a script I wrote to find matching values within multiple tables at once. I am currently returning empty resultsets where I've explicitly written to remove any row where the AssociatedId is empty. How can I write this to remove the empty resultsets?

Here is my SQL:

```
Select * From #Agreement

Declare @TableName nvarchar(256) 
Set @TableName = ''
While @TableName IS NOT NULL
Begin
    Set @TableName =  (
    Select top 1 MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
    From   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    Where  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
        AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Association%'
        AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) NOT IN ('[AssociationPrivilege]'
                                        , '[AssociationMultiplicityAssociation]'
                                        , '[AssociationPrivilegeAssociation]'
                                        , '[AssociationTypeAssociation]'
                                        , '[AssociationType]'
                                        , '[AsyncOperationResultsAssociation]'
                                        , '[AttributeGroupRoleMappingAssociation]'
                                        , '[EntityAttributeDataTypeAssociation]'
                                        , '[AutoDelegationAssociation]'
                                        , '[EntityAssociation]'
                                        , '[AssociationMultiplicity]'
                                        , '[RoleAssociationMapping]')
        Group BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    )

    Declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(500)
    Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT AssociationName, AssociatedId FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE AssociatedId 
        IN (Select AgreementSysID From #Agreement) AND CAST(AssociatedId AS NVARCHAR(255)) NOT IN ('''') 
        GROUP BY AssociationName, AssociatedId'
    Exec sp_executesql @SqlQuery
End
GO
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK Yes. I mean, empty result sets.

Comment: @DaleK Cool. I will notate that for the future. Thanks.

Comment: The real question is, why do you care about empty result sets? Surely its easier for have whatever process uses this data to ignore empty result sets?

Comment: @DaleK You're correct. I want to give this to someone else to use, and the empty result sets will throw them off.

Comment: @DaleK Should I remove the image?

Comment: @DaleK Ok, thank you for your guidance. I only post to SO if I really need an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second query to see how many records are going to be returned, and only run the select if there are results available.

```
    Declare @SQLQueryCount nvarchar(max), @SQLQueryResults nvarchar(max), @RecordCount int = 0, @WhereClause nvarchar(max);

    Set @WhereClause = ' WHERE AssociatedId 
        IN (Select AgreementSysID From #Agreement) AND CAST(AssociatedId AS NVARCHAR(255)) NOT IN ('''') 
        GROUP BY AssociationName, AssociatedId';

    Set @SQLQueryCount = 'SELECT @RecordCount = count(*) FROM ' + @TableName + @WhereClause;
    Set @SQLQueryResults = 'SELECT AssociationName, AssociatedId FROM ' + @TableName + @WhereClause;

    Exec sp_executesql @SqlQueryCount, N'@RecordCount int out', @RecordCount out;

    If @RecordCount > 0 Begin
        Exec sp_executesql @SqlQueryResult;
    End;
```

Note: For dynamic SQL I recommend always using `nvarchar(max)` because adding a length could cause very undesired results if you modified the query to make it longer than you can store.